# jquery/json: won't save ' and \

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, special-characters

I'm saving a text with jquery and json.

I'm getting the text of a textarea with .text() and saving it with json.
All special chars except \ and ' are saved.

If I try to save `%&$§/////blaääüü**´~+` it works, but if i try to save
`%&$§/////blaääüü**´~+\\\\\\\'''''` it does not work!

How can i solve this?

**Edit**

The code for the saving is: *(extract)*

```
$.ajax({
        url: "myURI"
                , type: "POST"
                , dataType: "json"
                , data:
                "{ " +
                "', 'text': '" + $('#myText').text() +
                "' }"
                , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        });
```

Comment: How do you "save" the text? Please post your code.

Comment: I have added the code in my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, your main problem is that the JSON you create is not valid and that you create it "manually". The result of your string concatenation is :

```
{ ', 'text': '%&$§/////blaääüü**´~+\\\'''''' }
```

which does not really look like JSON.

Use [`JSON.stringify` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) ([external library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) available as well) instead:

```
data: JSON.stringify({text: $('#myText').text()})
```

Further issues:

- Keys in JSON must be in double quotes, not single quotes.
- The fact that the text contains the escape character (`\`) and single quotes (`'`) messes up with the final string you create. That's why you should leave proper escaping of the content and the creation to the browser.
- Depending on the server side language you use, you should assign the JSON to a key, so that a proper key-value pair is sent to the server:

  ```
  data: {json: JSON.stringify(...)}
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer.
I still have a problem:
It won't save anything if I try to use stringify.
data: { json: JSON.stringify({
val1: $('#val1').val(),
val2: $('#val2').val(),
text: $('#myText').text()
})
}

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't save anything"? What is the data you receive on the server side? Are you accessing it properly? The JSON is created properly: http://jsfiddle.net/mkKKx/ So whatever problem you have, it seems to be on the server side.

Comment: on success it alerts "success" and on error saving it sends an error.I'm getting the error "invalid json-primitive: json"

Comment: Then you are processing your data differently. Remove the `json` part then: `data: JSON.stringify(...)`